# Is there a way to display a PDF that was converted to Bytes into a Browser? (not Windows Application) ASP.NET/VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm coding in ASP.NET/VB.Net (NOT a console or windows application). I am having trouble understanding how to display a PDF or file that has been converted to Bytes to a web Browser. I do understand that I have to convert the file to Bytes from a Stream or Memory Stream. I'm Using an OLD plugin PDF4NET to try to accomplish this.

I've looked at tons of stuff online and they're all using C#. I am using Visual Basic (not c#).

Comment: What do you mean by "a PDF or file that has been converted to Bytes to a web Browser."

Comment: for example if I have bytes(file), How do I display them via the web Browser? (in PDF format

Comment: I've seen examples where people use Response class but it did not work for me

Comment: You Shell to your browser like Shell("Firefox file:///c:/path/file.pdf", false, 60000). I hope that helps.